# What do I assign the value of i to carry it out of the loop to put in an system out?

Tags: java

For some reason I'm drawing a blank. How do I assign the value i so that it looks like this:

```
Burger: ***
```

```py
    for (int i = 1; i <= burgerCount; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("*");
    }

    System.out.println("Burgers: " + (the value of i here somehow) );
```

Comment: You want the value of `i` or the asterisks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using a string/string builder to store the asterisks in the loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=1; i <= burgerCount; i++) {
    sb.append("*");
}

System.out.println("Burgers: " + sb.toString());
```

This answer should be adequate, unless of course the burgers are coming from McDonald's, in which case you might not want to eat any of them.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked perfectly! And for that joke lol, I needed that! And I agree, we don't want to discuss McDonald's.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The main driver for using a `StringBuilder` here is to avoid instantiating a new string for each iteration of the loop.  Doing a single concatenation at the very end of the method/program is a minor penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out:

```
 System.out.print("Burger: ");
 for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
 }
```

In your question, you said "print the value of i here". If you print i, you will get the numbers 1,2,3 - as defined in your for loop. Instead of printing i, you can print "*". The for loop is only there to loop 3 times, as that is how many asterisks you want.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int burgerCount = 3;
int i=1;
for (;i <= burgerCount; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Burgers: " + i);
```

}

You will have to declare i out of for loop's scope if you want to access it outside of for loop.

Comment: I think I tried doing something like that but it didn't work. I used your code to test but it ends up giving me the number of asterisks and not the * itself. As well as seemingly putting the the actually asterisks in a weird spot. But thanks for commenting! I appericate you trying to help!

Comment: @JackieTowns You did ask for "the value of i".